# Множественные копии при проверке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

В очереди проверок при нескольких копиях показываются вкладки

> [Вопрос  —  Количество копий 1  —  Общее число копий: 2](//ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/71356)

[image: Вопрос - Количество копий 1 - Общее число копий: 2]

Думаю, должно быть по аналогии с одной копией:

> Вопрос  —  Копия 1  —  Копия 2

---

А ещё стоит проверить сами сообщения - почему в первом нет двоеточия, а во втором есть?

Comment: Не встречал подобной ситуации, поэтому использовал ваш вариант. Если что–то не так, пожалуйста, дайте знать!

Answer (score 2):

на всякий случай — ссылки на переводы:

[tx 3537](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265356) (вариант: one) *Duplicate $duplicateCount$*
**перевод:** *Количество копий $duplicateCount$*

[tx 5609](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40267656) (вариант: few) *Duplicate $duplicateCount$*
**перевод:** *Общее число копий: $duplicateCount$*

[tx 5610](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40267657) (вариант: many) *Duplicate $duplicateCount$*
**перевод:** *Общее число копий: $duplicateCount$*

---

по-моему, здесь всё же речь о **количестве** копий, а не о порядковом номере копии.

Comment: В каком смысле о количестве копий? При переходе на вкладку там отображается соответствующий вопрос-копия.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не знаю, что это может означать. это лишь моё предположение. я встречал подобное лишь один раз и не обратил внимания на цифры.

Comment: для памяти: [tx 3049](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264868) *Duplicate*