# Дибликаты — это вам не копии

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Вот тут уже поднимался вопрос о наименовании заголовков над копиями/дубликатами в очереди проверок: [Множественные копии при проверке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2787/178576)

А [сейчас](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/113187) вместо предлагаемого «копия 1» стоит «общее число дибликатов:1» (да, именно «дибликатов»):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предлагаю:

- либо исправить опечатку, либо, лучше, использовать слово «копия»
- всё-таки убрать не относящееся к делу «общее число»

Comment: Отметьте что ли галочкой, а то Дух уже два раза поднимал вопрос.

Comment: @alexolut, проголосуйте что ли за какой-нибудь ответ, а то дух скоро выдохнется.

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент момент исправил на «Дубликат № N». Копии или дубликаты – [отдельный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3723/). Буду рад услышать ваши соображения по данному вопросу!

Answer (score 0):

моё предложение:

- в случае одной копии писать: «копия»
- в случае нескольких копий:

  - либо: «копия 1», «копия 2», …
  - либо: «копия номер 1», «копия номер 2», …

принципиальных возражений по замене слова «копия» на слово «дубликат» не имею, кроме чисто эстетических.

Comment: [Обновил переводы](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265356?key=00621f47bab8d990f8053a5a3a7b4665). Годится?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, «дубликат № 1»? да, я думаю, это гораздо лучше, чем «общее число дубликатов: 1».

Comment: для памяти: [tx 3049](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264868) *Duplicate*